# How to hide one of loggedInPages item in ionic-conference-app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to hide one of loggedInPages items in [Ionic Conference App](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)

For example I have an admin Page. When user logged in application, user can see admin page link in loggedInPages if user's role is admin .

```js
loggedInPages: PageInterface[] = [
    { title: 'Account', name: 'AccountPage', component: AccountPage, icon: 'person' },
    { title: 'Support', name: 'SupportPage', component: SupportPage, icon: 'help' },
    { title: 'Logout', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, icon: 'log-out', logsOut: true },
    { title: 'Admin', name: 'Admin', component: AdminPage, icon: 'unlock'}
  ];
```

```html
<ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>
          Account
        </ion-list-header>
        <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of loggedInPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon" [color]="isActive(p)"></ion-icon>
          {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loggedInPages field as it is in ngFor loop, you can create a function like getLoggedInPagesAsPerUserRole() which will return only the pages according to the role of the logged in user.